# Programa .py a .exe

Tags: python, exe

¡Saludos, gente! Disculpen, he intentado convertir un programa mío realizado en Python 3.10.1 a un ejecutable de extensión .exe. El problema, es que, una vez instalado pyinstaller (es decir que ya escribí pip install pyinstaller para ello) e intentar con la conversión de extensión me arroja el típico error de que pyinstaller no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo. Y también que considerase añadir el directorio de pip.exe a un PATH (sin embargo no sé a qué se refiere este punto).
Si pudiesen ayudarme con ello, o darme alternativas a mi problema, lo agradecería enteramente.

Comment: Hola, nuevamente te invitamos a leer [ask], procura agregar lo que trataste o investigaste en tus preguntas, saludos.

Comment: Y probaste a buscar en google "agregar path windows"? Agregar rutas al path es algo muy común en informática, y necesario para muchos de los procesos requeridos a la hora de programar (y de usar el pc en general también, aunque se ve menos hoy en día). Y como tal, hay una cantidad excepcional de tutoriales que te indican paso a paso lo que debes hacer, y el proceso es el mismo para cualquier ruta que necesites, simplemente en vez de usar la ruta que usen en el tutorial, usas la que te hace falta a ti en este caso